# Select range based on number entered in any cell

Tags: vba, excel

So far I have gotten the VBA code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Value > 0 Then Target.Resize(, Application.Min(400, 2 * Target.Value)).Select

End Sub
```

This does what I want; Selects a range based on a number (*2, with a max limit of 400 cells selected) that I write anywhere in my workbook. The problem that I need help with is that i get a runtime-error 13 if I type something (Text) or delete something. Any idea on how I can modify this code would be greatly appreciated.

//Chris

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: What do you want the code edit to change? Would you like to add error handling to message the user if text is inputted?

Comment: `If Val(Target.Cells(1).Value) > 0` should do it

Comment: Thank you Rory. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Nilambar and Evan - I am sorry if I was unclear about what I wanted. I will be more specific in the future. Thanks anyway.

Comment: There is still one issue left. If i type numbers followed by a text I still encounter the same error as before. Ex. 123A or 123-

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent your next actions from re-triggering the same macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value > 0 Then
        Target.Resize(, Application.Min(400, 2 * Target.Value)).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the VBA I ended up with.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo Error_handler:
If Val(Target.Cells(1).Value) > 0 Then Target.Resize(, Application.Min(400,    2 * Target.Value)).Select
Exit Sub
Error_handler:
MsgBox "Error Handler"
End Sub
```

This will select the range specified by the cell value and also allow for text and other editing to be made as well as handling eventual errors by showing the MsgBox "Error Handler"